# Advanced Queries in Mongo or MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, mongodb

I'm developing a small application for and I was torn as to use MongoDB or MySQL for content storage.

I have approximately 2000 DB content pieces that have a multitude of meta data describing the content (id, name, type, descriptive tags, color, etc, date, views, etc.), now we need to return an array of objects that match certain criteria, so for example:

We need 30 objects returned based on a search or filter...

- 30% of those objects need to be animals
- 30% of them need to be an image
- 20% need to be videos
- 15% need to be products
- 5% need to be games

**But furthermore of the 30% of animals returned, let's say X amount has to be dinosaurs, X has to be monkeys, X has to be birds.**

*The same can be said for images, where from the 30% of images, the objects returned have to be equal parts of the different subcategories (cute, design, fashion, food, music, etc.)*

If that makes sense to anyone, what route would you suggest to go for the content database that is returning these objects, something tells me this would be easier to accomplish with MongoDB but I'm not completely sure.

Any suggestions and query examples in either Mongo or MySQL would be extremely helpful and appreciated.

Comment: I can say that MongoDB would be easier to query like this as you can use actual code to query. You can iterate through your categories, you could even use an object with percentages as a reference for the query

Comment: Thanks Kavi, I thought I could do that. Do you by any chance have any quick examples that you can possibly throw together in Mongo just so I can get a better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The percentage part is probably the hardest. I can't think of a good way of expressing these percentages in a MongoDB or SQL query. You'll probably have to handle this on the application side.

Apart from this limitation, MongoDB should be better for you. I'm assuming the metadata can vary, so there is no fixed schema. If the metadata properties are always the same, a relational database would be better.

I did saw that some of your metadata is hierarchical. Animals can be dinosaurs, so there's inheritance there as well. Neither SQL nor MongoDB can handle inheritance very well.

There are other NoSQL options as well. [4store](http://4store.org/) is a triple store designed to store RDF data. RDF can handle hierarchies, inheritance, loose schema and queries very well. Graph databases such as [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/) are specially good at this as well (although 4store can handle graphs too).

Sample queries for several engines:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    content
INNER JOIN
    classification
ON
    classification.content_id = content.id
INNER JOIN
    classification as classification2
ON
    classification2.content_id = content.id
WHERE
    classification.name = 'animal'
AND
    classification2.name = 'bird'
```

You can make more joins for more classification filters. There are other ways of achieving something similar, but that depends on how your data would be modeled.

MongoDB queries could be like this:

```
db.content.insert( { data: "foobar", classification: ["animal", "bird", "page"] } );
db.content.find( { classification: { $all: [ "animal", "bird" ] } } );
```

Or maybe like this:

```
db.content.insert( { data: "foobar", type: { main: "animal", sub: "bird" } } );
db.content.find( { type: { $elemMatch: { main : "animal", sub: "bird" } } } );
```

An SPARQL query with 4store could be like:

```
SELECT
    ?s ?p ?o
WHERE {
    ?s <rdfs:type> <myvocab:bird>
}
```

Could you tell more about your data?

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexandre, that was extremely helpful. The data set is basically a collection of products with a large set of meta data that act as descriptive elements, as you stated there are multiple hierarchical relationships and there is inheritance as well. I'll take a look into neo4j, that seems like the perfect solution. Again really appreciate the help, thank you!